# Mysql Database Design for User Created Retro Achievement Based Website

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-structures

**Background Story**

A little back story before i get to the question.

- I'm working on a Mysql driven site that allows people to track user
  created achievements for "retro" games.
- Ive been hand tracking the achievements up to this point, but would
  like to open it up for everyone with a honor based self checking
  system.
- Ive got the login working, so there is a login table, with username
  and password. (also other columns tho i dont think its matters to the
  answer).
- Originally, i was going to create a table per user, which id hope
  would get into the thousands, but after reading post on the site, ive
  come to understand that is a bad idea.

**Questions**

My question is the following:

What is the most efficient table(s) structure?

- I want each user to have a list of the achievements per game, with
  achieved and non-achieved represented, so they will need to be able
  to add games from a pre-set list.
- There will be multiple lists as most people have more than 1 game.
- I think this is a many to many relationship, but I'm not quite sure
  how to link all the elements together so i can start writing the
  queries.

Thanks for reading this post and any advice provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create several tabels representing each of their own parts of your system. Example.

```
Table 'Users':
id
username
password
usesgames

Table 'Games':
id
gamename
gamedescription

Table 'Achievements':
id
gameid
userid
achievement
points
```

Now, you can create as many users as possible, without interfering with the achievements vice versa.
Imagine you create two games. Age of Empires and Age of Empires II. Those will be created in the database with

```
1 Age of Empires - A fun strategy game
2 Age of Empires II - Version two of a fun strategy game
```

Lets then say, that user "BoomBlaster" own both games, you could make a comma seperated list in that users "usesgames" tabel row, like this

```
1,2
```

Imagining your using PHP you would be able to seperate those by using the `explode();` function

```
$games = "1,2";
$gamesarray = explode(",",$games);
```

Yet to this, you can now connect the user and the game toghetter to fetch the achievements in the database table "Achievements" By saying

```
SElECT * FROM Achievements WHERE gameid = $gameid AND userid = $userid;
```

I hope you see my point.
Best regards.
Jonas

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I have a question about using a single enter for the games tho.  Currently, there are 45 games with achievement sets. Would having a single entry house the games be able to handle 400 or even 1000 games or should i structure the table differently?

Comment: Hi. The only place you will have a single entry for the game will be in the users usesgame row. If you believe that it will be too much data in one row, you could also just create a new table called user_games with "userid, gameid" etc. I hope you understand this short message, else i will redo my post to be more clear. Best regards Jonas

Comment: I think @somomomo's idea is better - to create an achievements table and a separate user achievements table.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a users, games, achievements, and user_achievements tables. Each entry in the achievement table can be linked to a game id. When a user achieves a certain achievement, you can add an entry with the user_id and achievement_id in the user_achievements table. If there is no entry for that user and achievement, that means they have not achieved it.